# Update multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8, insert-update

How do I update the two tables, I have 2 tables, order and product, I want to update the product data on the order, I do it with the following code, but the product doesn't want to update

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id , Product $product)
{
    $request->validate([
        'do_code' => 'required',
        'delivery_date' => 'required',
        'qty' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'customer_id' => 'required',
        'armada_id' => 'required',
        'send_from_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    $data = Delivery_order::find($id);
    $data->update($request->all());
    if (count($request->product_name) > 0) {
        foreach ($request->product_name as $item => $v) {
            $data2 = array(
                'order_id' => $id,
                'product_name' => $request->product_name[$item],
                'qty' => $request->qty[$item],
                'tonise' => $request->tonise[$item]
            );
            $product->update($data2);
        }
    }
    return redirect('/do')->with('success', 'Data Successfully Updated');
}
```

Comment: "but the product doesn't want to update" ? Why tho? Any errors?

Comment: update your question with the related route and error if any. and what's the purpose of updating same product in each loop?? doesn't make sense.

Comment: Show us your $id and $product, use dd($id) before request validation

Answer (score 1):

Use just like this

```
 $product->order_id     = $id,
 $product->product_name = $request->product_name[$item],
 $product->qty          = $request->qty[$item],
 $product->tonise       = $request->tonise[$item]     
 $product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use [Laravel Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) to update the second table.